# Реакция браузера на "страница в странице"

Tags: ajax, html, iframe, javascript

Ребят, у меня такой вопрос.
Как отреагируют браузера если я сделаю страницу, где два раза тег `<HTML>` а потом его два раза закрою?
То есть схема будет примерно такая:

```
 <html>
  <body>
  ...
   <div>
    <html>
      ...
    </html>
   </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Если плохо, то могу ля использовать фреймы?
Если да, то как мне загружать фрейм функцией Ajax?

Comment: а зачем вам это ?

Comment: @eicto Хочу сделать что то вроде этого http://math.younet.pro

Comment: не стоит так делать. нормальных способов полно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы вставите тег `<html>` в середину документа, браузер в лучшем случае его проигнорирует. Использовать фреймы можно, но зачем, если вы все равно хотите грузить данные AJAX-ом? Короче, хотите фреймы - грузите ссылкой с атрибутом target, хотите AJAX - грузите AJAX-ом и пишите в div.

Answer (score 0):

что мешает использовать те-же контент-слайдеры? метод с фрэймами уже давно устарел, ajax был-бы более уместен.

Answer (score 0):

Если я не ошибаюсь, то в примере, который вы привели, вывод страниц реализован через PHP, что делается довольно легко... Если надо сделать так же, то и Аякса не надо... Если надо помочь, пишите, задавайте вопросы...